# Azure AD B2C + Azure Mobile Apps - MobileServiceInvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

We're trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app#azure-mobile-app-configuration) tutorial and run Client-Managed Authentication on Android. Here's how we configured our application in Azure AD B2C:

[image]

Then in Azure Mobile Apps we're enabling Azure AD authentication:

[image]

where `Issuer Url` ends with `v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` and contains B2C tenant Id taken from Azure Portal (Directory + subscription menu).

Then in Xamarin we have following code:

```
ADB2CClient = new PublicClientApplication(Constants.ClientID, // "48ab01cc-***********-73ef6c616da5"
        Constants.Authority); // https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/{Policy name}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
ADB2CClient.RedirectUri = Constants.RedirectUri; // "msal{ClientID}://auth

authenticationResult = await ADB2CClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
                            Constants.Scopes, // empty array
                            GetUserByPolicy(ADB2CClient.Users, 
                            Constants.PolicySignUpSignIn), // Policy name from AD B2C
                            Constants.Authority,  // https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/{Policy name}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
                        true);

var payload = new JObject();
if (authenticationResult != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authenticationResult.IdToken))
{
    payload["access_token"] = authenticationResult.IdToken;
}

User = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(
    MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,
    payload);
```

As a result we're able to get valid JWT token (`IdToken`) from `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method but every time we try to run `LoginAsync` we're getting `401` with following stack trace:

> {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

When we try to View Azure App Service logs it just says that

> Application: 2019-02-28T10:09:30  PID[7924] Information Sending response: 401.83 Unauthorized

without any additional details.

Rest of the code covers sample from [github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow)

Answer (score 1):

We’ve taken a look at this document/sample and can confirm that that it’s in need of a major refresh, as it’s no longer accurate. We are working internally to refresh it.

Thanks for bearing with us.